# 'Exiting' to shell after a .command

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal, shell

On OSX, with a .command file like

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Volumes/Volume/Path &&
executable --some "arg"
```

when I terminate the executable process (with CTRL-C), is there some way to leave the CLI session alive? I.e. so it returns to the prompt at `/Volumes/Volume/Path`.

The .command opens in iTerm2 and executes as

```
/Volumes/Volume/OtherPath/some.command; exit;
```

To simplify, just

```
cd /Volumes/Volume/Path
```

also exists the session. Isn't there a break or anything that can prevent `exit;`?

I've tried tacking on

```
... &&
$SHELL
```

(with(out) `exec` in front of `$SHELL`) but that didn't do anything. Also tried tacking on `set noclobber`, `set noclobber=1`, `exit 0`, `exit 1` and `pwd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by tacking on

open -a iTerm "`cd .`"

and making iTerm close (short-lived) sessions.

If anyone knows of a more elegant solution that just involves the shell and not starting iTerm with args, please add!

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Volumes/Volume/Path && executable --some "arg" &
```

Comment: Seems to just yield a short-lived session warning.